# Outputting times in local timezone in PHP

Tags: php, datetime

I am making a scheduling software, and I realized that the times I was inputting for the start/end times of events was actually in GMT, so, if I put an event for 7 AM, it would be 7 AM GMT making it a real issue when I would try to do actions such as figure out of an event is within 24 hours or so.

I used `date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York')` and now it is inputting the proper times.  So my 7 AM event is actually 11 AM GMT, which is fine (and accurate).

The problem is when I output from the database using something like `date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($event['start']))` - it will show me 11 AM, rather than the 7 AM local time.

Any ideas around this?

Comment: Wait.. why is 11 AM correct in the first case, but wrong in the second case?

Comment: Because an event starting at 7 AM in the America/New_York timezone, would be 11 AM GMT.

Comment: Still don't understand - if you set the timezone to `America/New_York`, why do you expect  the output to be in GMT?

Comment: I don't, but it is.

Comment: You should keep dates in UTC only – convert every date to UTC, but keep the timezone along for formatting purposes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `date_default_timezone_get();` to show the time zone.[Reference](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-get.php)

Comment: The timezone is set to America/New_York but date() is still outputting the GMT time

Comment: You have to call this method as well for displaying the time zone like this `echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime('2013-10-01')) . ' ' .  date_default_timezone_get();`

Comment: I don't want to display the time zone, I want the date/time to show up in eastern US time zone, but it is displaying it in GMT

Answer (score 0):

Letting the database aside (we have no information to determine how yours handles time zones) there're basically two possible approaches:

1. Ignore time zones altogether and make your application use a single hard-coded time zone. This sounds strange but it's surprisingly common in real world applications.
2. Make a very clear distinction between the actual value stored and the value displayed to user. In other words, don't blindly drop `strtotime()` and `date()` calls like crazy.

Both approaches have in common that you need to be fully aware at all times of what the time zone is. That means that you can't rely on defaults: your app needs to set its time zone explicitly everywhere it's needed, typically PHP itself ([`date_default_timezone_set()` function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php) or [`date.timezone` directive](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.configuration.php#ini.date.timezone)) and the database session (check your vendor documentation for details).

The main difference is that #1 is doesn't require time zone conversions so after you've configured everything you're basically done. In #2 you need to handle conversions from local time (for inputs) and to local time (for outputs):

After you've picked a reference time zone (typically `UTC`), you organise your code this way:

```
$appTimeZone = new DateTimeZone('UTC');
$userTimeZone = new DateTimeZone('America/New_York');

$input = new DateTime('2020-06-05 19:00:00', $userTimeZone);
echo 'Database time: ', $input->setTimezone($appTimeZone)->format('r'), "\n";
// Database time: Fri, 05 Jun 2020 23:00:00 +0000
$output = new DateTime('2020-06-05 23:00:00', $appTimeZone);
echo 'Display time: ', $output->setTimezone($userTimeZone)->format('r'), "\n";
// Display time: Fri, 05 Jun 2020 19:00:00 -0400
```

This can also be done with `date_default_timezone_set()`, I'm only using [DateTime](https://www.php.net/DateTime) because it's simpler.